# Random background change upon refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make it so that when the page is visited or refreshed, the background changes. I am trying to achieve this with JS.

This is the JS I currently have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var imgCount = 3;
    var dir = 'img/';
    var randomCount = Math.round(Math.random() * (imgCount - 1)) + 1;
    var images = new Array
            images[1] = "1.png",
            images[2] = "2.png",
            images[3] = "3.png",
    document.body.style.background = "url(" + dir + images[randomCount] + ")";
</script>
```

Along with the HTML:

```
<html>
    <head> 
            <!-- The JS was here but didnt liek to be pasted -->
            <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page">
            Rawr
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
html, body {
background: no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}

#page {
width: 900px;
height: auto;
border: #900 1px solid;
border-radius: 5px; 
float: right;
margin-right: 20px;
}
```

My main problem is that images; firstly - don't appear and secondly - I don't know if the script is working or not because of this.

My file tree is as simple as a root directory and a folder named 'img' for images with 3 images, 1 - 3 that are png's.

Please could someone help me establish why the background doesn't show up, if the code is actually working.

Thanks. Sorry if my posting is inadequate, I'm really not the best at this kind of thing =/

Comment: You've placed the script before the body in the DOM.

Comment: Also, it's `new Array();`

Comment: @adeneo You're wrong :)

Comment: @sabof - it would be great if you where a little more specific.

Comment: @adeneo Your point is valid stylistically. But `new Array` also creates an array, and the parentheses are optional.

Comment: @sabof - That's true, class constructors don't need the parenthesis, it's assumed if left out.

Answer (score 0):

As **adeneo** said you should put your script after DOM is ready, something like

**Update**
For not repeat the background you should use this snippet of code.

```
document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
```

**Full Code**

```
<html>
    <head> 
            <!-- The JS was here but didnt liek to be pasted -->
            <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page">
            Rawr
        </div>
    <!-- put your script is here after dom is ready -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var imgCount = 3;
        var dir = 'img/';
        var randomCount = Math.round(Math.random() * (imgCount - 1)) + 1;
        var images = new Array
                images[1] = "1.png",
                images[2] = "2.png",
                images[3] = "3.png",
        document.body.style.background = "url(" + dir + images[randomCount] + ")";
        document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat"; 
        //----^----for not repeat the background
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I now get the problem that i cannot stop the background from repeating. I have background-repeat: no-repeat; but the background still repeats, and setting background-color: #000; covers half the background picture.